# What is the subject of this sentence? Does the sentence make sense?

Tags: sentence-construction, subjects

> “The quality of written work submitted for his Science Final should have been completed with more thought and care".

Comment: It doesn't make much sense since one can't complete quality. That aside, the subject is "the quality of written work submitted for his science final".

Comment: I agree, thank you! We were debating if the subject is “ quality” or “work”.

Comment: @BillJ: why don't you make that a proper answer? It can be voted, and the question closed, if you do.